# exception invalid syntax while formatting arguments for property

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm maintaining a project [cssutils](https://pypi.org/project/cssutils) ([Github](https://github.com/jaraco/cssutils)). The Sphinx docs builds currently emit errors like:

```
WARNING: error while formatting arguments for cssutils.css.CSSStyleSheet.namespaces: Handler <function update_defvalue at 0x10524c0e0> for event 'autodoc-before-process-signature' threw an exception (exception: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='? (<unknown>, line 2))
```

I tried inspecting the source, but struggled to find the source of `CSSStyleSheet.namespaces`. So instead, I inspected the docstrings of that class and attribute, but still didn't find anything that looked like invalid syntax:

```
 ~ $ pip-run cssutils
Python 3.11.3 (main, Apr  7 2023, 20:13:31) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cssutils.css
>>> cssutils.css.CSSStyleSheet.namespaces
<property object at 0x1053a2570>
>>> cssutils.css.CSSStyleSheet.namespaces.__doc__
'All Namespaces used in this CSSStyleSheet.'
>>> print(cssutils.css.CSSStyleSheet.__doc__)
CSSStyleSheet represents a CSS style sheet.

    Format::

        stylesheet
          : [ CHARSET_SYM S* STRING S* ';' ]?
            [S|CDO|CDC]* [ import [S|CDO|CDC]* ]*
            [ namespace [S|CDO|CDC]* ]* # according to @namespace WD
            [ [ ruleset | media | page ] [S|CDO|CDC]* ]*

    ``cssRules``
        All Rules in this style sheet, a :class:`~cssutils.css.CSSRuleList`.
```

How can I trace the cause of this class of error?

Comment: I've discovered that by replacing a [lambda-based property](https://github.com/jaraco/cssutils/blob/9e6cee056f3743b223d5550d11e01fbeb99b2c10/cssutils/profiles.py#L214-L216) with a typical function, the error disappears, so I'm suspecting a bug/limitation in Sphinx.

Comment: Annoyingly, I can't repro the issue in an isolated build, even if I take the whole `profiles.py` (minus its import on cssutils).

Comment: Aha. I can repro as long as I include `autodoc_preserve_defaults = True`.

Comment: I filed a [bug with the project](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/11459).